# Is there a way I can reduce the code for generating simple circuits with the same structure?

Tags: programming, qiskit

here's the code I'm using to generate 3 quantum circuits with the same structure (They're only differed by the first U3 gate on the qubit):

```
quancs = QuantumCircuit(1)  # Circ 1
quancs.u3(gamma,beta,delta,0)
        
quancs1 = QuantumCircuit(1) # Circ 2
quancs1.u3(2,3,2,0)         
quancs1.u3(gamma,beta,delta,0)
        
quancs2 = QuantumCircuit(1) # Circuit 3. 
quancs2.u3(-2.5,2,-2,0)
quancs2.u3(gamma,beta,delta,0)
        
results = execute(quancs, simulator).result()
results1 = execute(quancs1, simulator).result()
results2 = execute(quancs2, simulator).result()
```

I treated the circuits separately to obtain the results. I'm wondering is there a way I can simplify/shorten this code? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
from qiskit.circuit import QuantumCircuit
def my_circuit(initial_gate_params, params):
    circuit = QuantumCircuit(1)
    circuit.u3(initial_gate_params[0],initial_gate_params[1],initial_gate_params[2],0)         
    circuit.u3(params[0], params[1], params[2], 0)
    return circuit 


initial_gate_params = [ [0,0,0], [2,3,2], [-2.5,2,-2] ] #the params for your initial u3 gate
params = [gamma, beta, zeta] #your defined gamma, beta, zeta

circuits = [my_circuit(i, params) for i in initial_gate_params ]

from qiskit import Aer, execute
backend = Aer.get_backend('qasm_simulator')
results = execute(circuits, backend)
```

Comment: That looks great, thank you!